# Best way to get Current User session in Ember with Torii

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-data, emberfire

I would like to know what the best way is to get the User Model Record of the current logged in user. I'm using torii in combination with corresponding firebase adapter.

**app/torri-adapters/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ToriiFirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/torii-adapters/firebase';

export default ToriiFirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

For example: I have a client model and at this moment i have this very ugly solution to query all client records associated with the current logged in user:

**app/routes/clients.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return this.store.query('user', {
      orderBy: 'email',
      equalTo: this.get('session.currentUser.email')
    }).then(function(user) {
      var myUser = user.get('firstObject');
      return _this.store.query('client', {
        orderBy: 'user',
        equalTo: myUser.id
      }).then(function(client) {
        return client;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

For sure there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Here is a working [example](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2015/06/18/how-to-inject-the-current-user-using-ember-simple-auth/) how to create service.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the `currentUser` into all your controllers, routes and components at the app initialization, so you will be able to refer to the current user simply by doing `this.get('currentUser')` wherever you need it. See the section which shows an example of how this is done here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/dependency-injection/